# Licensing Chrome Web Apps

Tags: licensing, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have written a Chrome Packaged App and I am now ready to publish to the Chrome Web Store.

I wish to offer a fully featured free trial period (eg 14 days) before requiring the user to buy a license.
I have read [this article](http://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments) concerning how to receive the current license state and using the example code from github have got the license status to work.

However, how do I actually "set" the license? 
The example code returns "NONE" in the response. How do I activate a Free Trial programmatically or update this value when the customer purchases a license?

Answer (score 1):

The licenses will be set automatically by Web Store. When a user chooses "free trial" to install your app, the access level will be set to "FREE_TRIAL". For the paid version of your app, the access level will be set to "FULL". If you have followed the instructions in the article properly, your app would be able to query licenses from Web Store.

Comment: Ok Thanks - but how do I enable my app to have a Free Trial then?